# Select a random class from inner classes

Tags: groovy

I have this kind of solution

```
interface Type {

  static class Arial implements Type { .. }

  static class ComicSans implements Type { .. }

  ..

}
```

then I need to pass the class to a method, e.g.

```
someMethod(Type.Arial)
```

How can I randomly select the type to that method?

```
def randomType = ???
someMethod(randomType)
```

Comment: Create an array of classes and choose a random int between zero to the array-size minus 1 which will be used as an index to a random class.

Comment: @alfasin any solution not requiring to re-type all class names and maintaining the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get list of `Type`'s inner classes with:

```
Type.classes
```

Picking random one should be easy :)

Comment: this is really nice! Any similar behaviour to list classes in a package?

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that there's no such feature. But you can take a look at this implementation: http://www.dzone.com/snippets/get-all-classes-within-package